# Problem with timezone

Tags: 7, datetime

When I edit my node I have this date

[image]

But when I save the system change the Time:
[image]

I really don't understand because my timezone on the server and drupal are the same.
And my field is well configured:

[image]

For your information
[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: when you view the node the time is displayed 11:16 or 12:16?

Comment: No its 11:16 but I think I have my answer, Drupal save in UTC and apply the timezone during the rendering so I have to display my result with format_date()